# Compare signed integers as if they were unsigned

Tags: postgresql, integer

I am using PostgreSQL to store 64 bits IDs. The IDs  are unsigned and make full use of all their bits (including the first one). To store said IDs, I am currently converting them to signed integers before inserting them as `bigint` (because Pg doesn't support unsigned integers).

This does work, and I am able to convert back the IDs to unsigned integers after querying them, but I ran into a problem: if I try to compare IDs in an SQL request, it will fail because some of them are negative.

For example, if I try to store `18446744069414584320` and `25` inside my DB, those IDs will be stored as `-4294967296` and `25` respectively. Hence for Pg, the largest ID would be `25` (which is problematic in my case).

Is there a way to treat signed integers as unsigned when using a comparison operator in PostgreSQL ?

Edit: Storing the IDs using the `numeric` data type would not be practical in my case not only because of the increased memory consumption but also because of the way IDs are processed by the applications connected to the database.

Comment: Store your values not as converted signed bigints but as DECIMAL or BYTEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare like

```
a > b OR a < 0 AND b >= 0
```

An `ORDER BY` clause could be

```
ORDER BY a < 0, a
```

(which works because `FALSE < TRUE`).

Or you could do the smart thing and use the data type `numeric` that allows you to store the numbers as they are.

Comment: The overhead of using the `numeric` type would be too big for the size of the dataset I am working with (as it would double the size taken by every ID).

Comment: If space is more important than ease of use, go with the comparison I suggested.

Comment: I have tried your answer and it works, thank you.
Do you know how I could use this in an `order by` clause ?

Answer (score 1):

I think Peter Eisentraut's [pguint](https://github.com/petere/pguint) extension solves your problem by implementing a new `uint8` data type that can be compared and indexed.